# PHP pass variable to include

Tags: php, variables, include, global-variables, global

I'm trying to pass a variable into an *include* file. My host changed PHP version and now whatever solution I try doesn't work.

I think I've tried every option I could find. I'm sure it's the simplest thing!

The variable needs to be set and evaluated from the calling first file (it's actually `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, and needs to return the path of that file, not the included `second.php`).

**OPTION ONE**

In the first file:

```
global $variable;
$variable = "apple";
include('second.php');
```

In the second file:

```
echo $variable;
```

**OPTION TWO**

In the first file:

```
function passvariable(){
    $variable = "apple";
    return $variable;
}
passvariable();
```

**OPTION THREE**

```
$variable = "apple";
include "myfile.php?var=$variable"; // and I tried with http: and full site address too.


$variable = $_GET["var"]
echo $variable
```

None of these work for me. PHP version is 5.2.16.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try denining a constant ?

Comment: you dont have to pass variables in to include files. your webserver will just load the code of your files when you include them just like if you had written that code from the include file in to your other file.

Comment: Could you clarify 'None of these works'? Error messages will be helpful, too... And, AFAIK, included code is executed within the same context, so `global` is not necessary; your first option should run just fine.

Comment: As others said, the include() is just like pasting the code there, it continues the execution of the code just like being in same file. You don't have to find a way to include the variable in the include file, you can simply write it before the include() (if needed).

Answer (score 73):

Speaking of passing a variable to include, it doesn't need any special action: any php variable defined prior calling include is *already* available in the included file (given it's available in the scope where include is called). This is exactly how include works.

While in order to pass a set of variables into a *function* that calls include inside, you can use [extract()](http://php.net/extract)
Drupal use it, in its `theme()` function.

Here it is a render function with a `$variables` argument.

```
function includeWithVariables($filePath, $variables = array(), $print = true)
{
    // Extract the variables to a local namespace
    extract($variables);

    // Start output buffering
    ob_start();

    // Include the template file
    include $filePath;

    // End buffering and return its contents
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    if (!$print) {
        return $output;
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

**./index.php :**

```php
includeWithVariables('header.php', array('title' => 'Header Title'));
```

**./header.php :**

```php
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

Comment: You can also use this method adding the **EXTR_REFS** flag to the extract function (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) so that when you pass a variable with reference: `array( 'title' => &$title )` the $title can be changed inside the included file.

Comment: I don't think this works in later versions of PHP, say 7.3

Comment: It works in (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8), thank you for this answer, should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 54):

Option 3 is impossible - you'd get the rendered output of the .php file, exactly as you would if you hit that url in your browser. If you got raw PHP code instead (as you'd like), then ALL of your site's source code would be exposed, which is generally not a good thing.

Option 2 doesn't make much sense - you'd be hiding the variable in a function, and be subject to PHP's variable scope. You'ld also have to have `$var = passvariable()` somewhere to get that 'inside' variable to the 'outside', and you're back to square one.

option 1 is the most practical. `include()` will basically slurp in the specified file and execute it right there, as if the code in the file was literally part of the parent page. It does look like a global variable, which most people here frown on, but by PHP's parsing semantics, these two are identical:

```
$x = 'foo';
include('bar.php');
```

and

```
$x = 'foo';
// contents of bar.php pasted here
```

Comment: "Slurp in"? I'm sorry I cannot find a good definition for this!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo "Slurp" means to read the entire contents of a file and put the whole contents somewhere. Basically, `include()` copies the included file and pastes its contents in place of the `include()` function.

Answer (score 14):

Considering that an include statment in php at the most basic level takes the code from a file and pastes it into where you called it and the fact that the manual on include states the following:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward.

These things make me think that there is a diffrent problem alltogether. Also Option number 3 will never work because you're not redirecting to `second.php` you're just including it and option number 2 is just a weird work around. The most basic example of the include statment in php is:

```
vars.php
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>

test.php
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

Considering that option number one is the closest to this example (even though more complicated then it should be) and it's not working, its making me think that you  made a mistake in the include statement (the wrong path relative to the root or a similar issue).

Comment: Perhaps I have confused the order of things?

The structure is, in fact:

main.php
$variable = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
include = 'http://side.com/footer.php;

footer.php:
echo $variable;

All the included file doesn't contain the variable, it merely does something to it.

In all the options I tried, the output is either blank, or includes $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] of the footer.php and not the main.php.

Is this different?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem here, you may use the $GLOBALS array.

```
$GLOBALS["variable"] = "123";
include ("my.php");
```

It should also run doing this:

```
$myvar = "123";
include ("my.php");

....

echo $GLOBALS["myvar"];
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: This answer is self-contradicting. WHY "use the $GLOBALS array", if $myvar = "123"; "also run"?

Comment: Hello Common Sense, user1590646 describes a php configuration where this is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this issue where I had a file that sets variables based on the GET parameters.  And that file could not updated because it worked correctly on another part of a large content management system.  Yet I wanted to run that code via an include file without the parameters actually being in the URL string. The simple solution is you can set the GET variables in first file as you would any other variable.

Instead of:

```
include "myfile.php?var=apple";
```

It would be:

```
$_GET['var'] = 'apple';
include "myfile.php";
```

Answer (score 5):

**OPTION 1** worked for me, in PHP 7, and for sure it does in PHP 5 too. And the global scope declaration is not necessary for the included file for variables access, the included - or "required" - files are part of the script, only be sure you make the "include" AFTER the variable declaration. Maybe you have some misconfiguration with  variables global scope in your PHP.ini?

Try in first file:

```
  <?php 
  $myvariable="from first file";
  include ("./mysecondfile.php"); // in same folder as first file LOLL
  ?>
```

mysecondfile.php

```
  <?php 
  echo "this is my variable ". $myvariable;
  ?>
```

It should work... if it doesn't just try to reinstall PHP.

Answer (score 4):

In regards to the OP's question, specifically "The variable needs to be set and evaluated from the calling first file (it's actually '$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']', and needs to return the path of that file, not the included second.php)."

This will tell you what file included the file. Place this in the included file.

```
$includer = debug_backtrace();
echo $includer[0]['file'];
```

Comment: Based on the OP's comments in his question
"The variable needs to be set and evaluated from the calling first file (it's actually '$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']', and needs to return the path of that file, not the included second.php)."
He needs to find out what the path is of the file that did the including of second.php.

Comment: Noted. (it's not clear from your answer, please clarify it ["since OP wants to get the original file name blah blah blah"]).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but stumbled upon it now and saw nobody mentioned this. so writing it.

The Option one if tweaked like this, it should also work.

**The Original**

> **Option One**
>
> In the first file:
>
> ```
> global $variable; 
> $variable = "apple"; 
> include('second.php');
> ```
>
> In the second file:
>
> `echo $variable;`

**TWEAK**

In the first file:

```
$variable = "apple"; 
include('second.php');
```

In the second file:

```
global $variable;
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to php docs (see [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is the "filename of the currently executing script".

The INCLUDE statement "includes and evaluates the specified" file and "the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs" (see [INCLUDE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)).

I believe $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will return the filename of the 1st file, even when used by code in the 'second.php'.

I tested this with the following code and it works as expected ($phpSelf is the name of the first file).

```
// In the first.php file
// get the value of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for the 1st file
$phpSelf = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// include the second file
// This slurps in the contents of second.php
include_once('second.php');

// execute $phpSelf = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; in the secod.php file
// echo the value of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] of fist file

echo $phpSelf;  // This echos the name of the First.php file.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute all in "second.php" adding variable with jQuery

```
<div id="first"></div>

<script>
$("#first").load("second.php?a=<?=$var?>")
</scrpt>
```

Comment: Looping variables through frontend like this is a code-smell and should be avoided.

Comment: @Jonas Stensved, why? Give me a link with explication

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to using $GLOBALS is to store the variable value in $_SESSION before the include, then read it in the included file. Like $GLOBALS, $_SESSION is available from everywhere in the script.

Answer (score -1):

Pass a variable to the include file by setting a $_SESSION variable

e.g.

$_SESSION['status'] = 1;
include 'includefile.php';

// then in the include file read the $_SESSION variable

$status = $_SESSION['status'];

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this:

```
$_GET['varable']; // from your URL or anything
include "adminchat.php";
```

This will directly pass the variable data to any links or command written in other file.

Answer (score -3):

I found that the include parameter needs to be the **entire** file path, not a relative path or partial path for this to work.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. Relative paths work just fine in `include`'s. You just have to be sure you are assuming a correct "relative to what" beginning.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me: To wrap the contents of the second file into a function, as follows:

## firstFile.php

```
<?php
    include("secondFile.php");

    echoFunction("message");
```

## secondFile.php

```
<?php
    function echoFunction($variable)
    {
        echo $variable;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Do this:

```
$checksum = "my value"; 
header("Location: recordupdated.php?checksum=$checksum");
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Some explanation would be great.