# PHP - Dynamic navigation bar help needed

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make an Dynamic navbar for my website with `php`, and it worked
This is how it looks like now[image: alt text...]

And this is how I want to let it look like the page were I'm on is selected

[image: alt text..]

My code of the navbar:

```
<?php
echo "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-inverse\" role=\"navigation\">
      <div class=\"container\">
        <div class=\"navbar-header\">
          <a href=\"#\" class=\"navbar-brand\">
            Techzone
        </div>
        <div class=\"collapse navbar-collapse\">
        <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">
        <li><a href=\"/index.php\">Home</a></li>
        <li class=\"dropdown\"> <a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">What we offer<b class=\"caret\"></b></a>
        <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">
        <li><a href=\"/offers/websites.php\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-book\"> Websites</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"/offers/translations.php\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-font\"> Translations</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"/offers/programs.php\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"> Programs</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href=\"/websitesMade.php\">Our websites <span class=\"badge\">2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=\"/aboutus.php\">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class=\"navbar-form navbar-right\" role=\"search\">
        <div class=\"form-group\">
        <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Search\">
        </div>
        <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-default\">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>";
        }
        echo "</ul>
        <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">
        <li class=\"dropdown\">
          <a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Language <span class=\"caret\"></span></a>
          <ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\">
            <li><a href=\"../nl/index.php\">Nederlands</a></li>
            <li class=\"divider\"></li>
            <li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">English</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

        <form class=\"navbar-form navbar-right\" role=\"search\">
        <div class=\"form-group\">
        <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Search\">
        </div>
        <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-default\">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
";
?>
```

In my HTML page I'm using this code to let the navBar show up:
`<?php include '../navbar.php' ?>`

BTW, I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap for the navbar

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This isn't a PHP question

Comment: Well, I'm using PHP for the dynamic navBar...

Comment: Do you have the current page stored in a php variable or does each page have a unique css class / ID?

Comment: All the HTML classes use the same PHP class for the navbar, I use bootstrap for the navbar, so they all have the same CSS class

Comment: @JohnConde It could be / probably is, if the OP wants to add some style to a specific list item depending on the page that is displayed (using php...).

Comment: @jeroen True, but I don't see that being the case here.

Comment: @JohnConde I do, but I will leave it like this I guess. Moderators are always right...

Comment: Com'n... Someone gonna be my lifesaver?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the nicest solution but you can get the name of the webpage:

```
$bn = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* Returns The Current PHP File Name */
```

then run a check whenever you go to display it (or ofc a nicer method)

```
if($bn == "index.php") {
    $str += '<li><a class="current" href=\"/index.php\">Home</a></li>'
} else {
    $str += '<li><a href=\"/index.php\">Home</a></li>'
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put the most upper code in the navbar.php class? I did think about this method, but I though that it would just return navbar.php, but I will try this in a few minutes

Comment: Hmm, yeah didn't think of that, here's an SO question on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905140/php-pass-variable-to-include

Comment: I don't know what that is about, but I guess I can just for example make a form that gets triggered when someone loads the page, and that sends the name of the page to the php class

Comment: It seems like I can't manage it to create a efficient piece of code that isn't 100 lines long to solve this...