# Set parameters when require_once a php script

Tags: php, wordpress

First, I do not hope this question is too stupid for stackoverflow, but I am quite new to php and do not have much experience.

I have the file `page.php` and the file `sendTestMail.php` and I would like to run the file `sendTestMail.php` with specific parameters.

I am calling `sendTestMail.php` like that:

```
    require_once WPGAMAIL_PATH.'sendTestMail.php';
```

And I need to set two array parameters `$wp_set` and `$ga_set`.

Any suggestions what a best-practice solution is?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tons of possiblities, however without knowing the structure within your sendTestMail.php I can only give you hints.

You should basically create a function within your sendTestMail.php - e.g.

```
<?php
function sendTestMail($wp_set, $ga_set) {
  /* your actual code ...*/
}
```

If you now require the script you can simply call the function an pass the parameters

```
<?php 
require_once WPGAMAIL_PATH.'sendTestMail.php';

sendTestMail('john', 'doe'); // or whatever your parameters are
```

Other examples of how to pass variables to included / required files can be found here

[PHP pass variable to include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905140/php-pass-variable-to-include)