# PHP - How do I change the value of a text in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML `text` that let user to enter value for searching ID.

```
<input name="sname" type="text" id="sname" value="<?=$sname?>">
```

I'm now adding a HTML `button` to set the value of the `text` to blank after clicking.

```
<input type="submit" name="bth_clear" id="bth_clear" value="Clear">
```

I did it in the php but it doesn't work. The value entered is still there. Any ways that I can do ?

```
<?php   

if ($bth_clear) {
    $sname=""; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (isset($_POST['btn_clear']))` (assuming you're using `action="post"` in your form)? PHP's [_register globals_](http://php.net/manual/security.globals.php) went away a long time ago

Comment: I think you should consider doing that in JavaScript or jQuery. From the PHP perspective you will do this on the server side, the client side will not be affected by this button unless the screen is refreshed.

Comment: @RafaelBoszko I think it's safe to assume the PHP script renders the HTML page and OP is doing a normal form submit. Where else would `value="<?=$sname?>"` come from?

Comment: @RafaelBoszko the screen is refreshed everytime the button is clicked

Comment: @Phil `if (isset($_POST['btn_clear']))` won't work, my entire query went blank

Comment: @hatched That is meant to be in place of `if ($btn_clear)`. Please update the code in your question if yours has changed. Also, I see no _"query"_ at all so have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: fyi, it's `bth_clear`, not `btn_clear`

Comment: @kerbholz thanks, I fail at reading comprehension. OP, replace `if ($bth_clear)` with `if (isset($_POST['bth_clear']))` if it's a POST form, or `if (isset($_GET['bth_clear']))` otherwise

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a function that loads variables when you load the view.

Look here for the second answer [PHP pass variable to include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905140/php-pass-variable-to-include/48214397#48214397)

*How to use it ?*

```
if (isset($_POST['bth_clear'])) {

     $name = isset($_POST['sname']) && is_string($_POST['sname']) ? $_POST['sname'] : null;

     includeWithVariables('view/MyView.php', array('sname' => $name ));
}
```

*And in the view*

```
<input name="sname" type="text" id="sname" value="<?php echo isset($sname) ? $sname: null?>">
```

Like this you can save the data from the input and pass it back to the user in the same form that he sent or in another form .

Also using this way you **don't** have to include any PHP file in your View

Answer (score -2):

you can do it with jquery

```
   <script>$(document).ready(function(){var bth_clear = $("#bth_clear").val();if(bth_clear.length > 0){$("#bth_clear").val('');}});</script>
```

Comment: Question is not tagged with [tag:javascript]. OP is looking for a server-side solution

Comment: Nice and all, but Javascript/jQuery wasn't a requirement

Comment: first submit your form and after that give blank as you want.