# GET parameter is not null, but i can't use it on a PHP function

Tags: php, parameters, get, include, parameter-passing

Structure of the main file (index.php)

```
<?php
include('functions.inc.php');
include('page.php');
?>
```

In functions.inc.php file i definied a function:

```
function getServiceAddonButtons($product)
        {     
                global $db; 
                $service = getServiceVar($product);
                $svaddon = $service['svdo_addon'];
                if (file_exists('content/addons/'.$svaddon.'/service_buttons/buttons.php') && addon_activated($svaddon) == 'YES') {
                    include('content/addons/'.$svaddon.'/service_buttons/buttons.php'); 
                }
            }
```

(Other functions on this file are already definied and working good)

In page.php i used this function:

```
<div class='buttons'>
<?php getServiceAddonButtons($_GET['service_id']); ?>
</div>
```

When i'm on index.php (where page.php is shown because is included)
I use url `https://example.com/index.php?manage_service=1&service_id=218`

**THE PROBLEM:** Seems like every time i'm on this page, the parameter of function `getServiceAddonButtons($product)` is null, but i used `$_GET['service_id']`

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: have you try to echo GET variable for see result?

Comment: Yes, in page.php is returning the correct value (218)

Comment: You said '_getServiceAddonButtons($product) is null_' because don't return include true? or $service variable in the function not work? try to use echo in all part of the function for test if variable is want you want. And are you sure exist $svaddon folder ?

Comment: There is no problem with include, you see: there is a $product parameter in function, that's null even if i define it by using function($_GET['service_id'])

Comment: if you echo `$_GET['service_id']` before function and show correctly (218) it's impossible is null, and the problem is in the function.

Comment: *echo $_GET['service_id']* in file.php outputs 218 (correct value, but *echo $product* in function is returning nothing like the variable wasn't set.

Comment: Try to see if $service -  $svaddon containe correct data

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make the "include" AFTER the variable declaration.

```
<?php
$variable = $_GET['service_id'];
include('functions.inc.php');
include('page.php');
?>
```

This link contains all the details regarding your problem: [PHP pass variable to include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905140/php-pass-variable-to-include)